# How cosine similarity differs from Okapi BM25?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, information-retrieval, cosine-similarity

I'm conducting a research using elasticsearch. I was planning to use cosine similarity but I noted that it is unavailable and instead we have BM25 as default scoring function.

Is there a reason for that? Is cosine similarity improper for querying documents? Why was BM25 chosen as default?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Longtime elasticsearch use TF/IDF algorithm to find similarity in queries. But number versions ago is changed to BM25 as more efficient. You can read the information in [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/similarity.html). [And good article explains what is elastic search and how to the similarity in ES](https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/intro-doc-similarity-with-elasticsearch/).

You can also write a custom algorithm to elasticsearch. [Here a good article about how to do](http://stefansavev.com/blog/custom-similarity-for-elasticsearch/).